# como validar opciones de una lista desplegable python con selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

La  URL : https://cuentanos-tu-experiencia.xtracking.co/xtracking/proximate/filter, se requiere que el campo "Pais", seleccione la opcion "Colombia", pero antes de seleccionarla, que valide que estan las opciones "Colombia", "México" y "Peru", si no estan las opciones genere una alerta que indique cual ciudad falta, si estan las opciones,  que deje marcado colombia.Python con selenium.

Agradezco me puedan colaborar, soy nuevo y llevo tiempo intentando adecuar el codigo para que funcione.

Si alguien me puede colaborar les agradeceria.